# React JS : a style with condition is working but needs refreshing to apply properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui

Hello dear developers !

I am currently working on a Responsive UI/UX screen, in a React web app. The thing is, on a specific size of screen, I need to have the right padding on the general `<Grid>` downsized from 80px to 16, using `spacing()`.

It works fine, but, as it is applying only on 3 routes, 3 pages, it needs manual refreshes to resize on its original size or to go back on 16px padding.

Here is my code for this purpose, inside the `makeStyle` I'm using :

```
    containerWithoutItem: ({ pathname }: any) => ({
        paddingLeft: theme.spacing(10),
        overflow: 'auto',
        '@media screen and (max-width: 1100px)': {
          paddingRight: principleRoutes.includes(pathname) ? theme.spacing(2) : theme.spacing(10)
        }
      }),
```

And here is my `array` of the the `principleRoutes`, up, in the same file :

```
let principleRoutes = ['/home', '/home/board', '/home/products', '/home/history'];
```

Of course my `Component`, inside which is the `<Grid />` element, has the proper `props` declared : `pathname`, so it works fine, on exactly the routes I need it to work.

I just want to get rid of this refresh need. Because it isn't intuitive for the user, to refresh manually, as the project is on a tablet app purpose.

Comment: you dont really need to say thanks. actually its discouraged here. but welcome. but edit out the pleasantries from the question.

Comment: @Jay Fine, no problem ;)

Comment: Can you add how you are using the styles?